# Learning Command Line Basics for Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm just starting to use Github and am not very familiar with using command line.  Are there any good online resources for someone who is truly starting out?  I would really hate to nuke an entire project because I misunderstand the command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book about Linux shell programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449912/book-about-linux-shell-programming)

Comment: Are you asking about the 'git' command line or about general Linux command line stuff?  Your title is very generic, but your summary makes it sound like you want 'git' details.

Answer (score 1):

http://gitref.org/

^ This looks like a -really- good site for what you're looking for.